# Is possible keeps the contents of all files inside within a compressed tar.gz, like a stream?

Tags: java, ant, tar, compression

I have a problem to resolve.
I have tar.gz compressed file, and I wouldLike keep the contents like a stream, like Zipfile permits with the method zipFile.getInputStream(zipEntry). I have Implemented using ant library, the code:

```
TarInputStream is =  new TarInputStream(gzipInputStream);
while((entryx = is.getNextEntry()) != null) {
    if (entryx.isDirectory()) continue;
    else {
              InputStream tmpIn = new StreamingTarEntry(is,  entryx.getSize());
              BufferedReader gzipReader = null;
```

`// simple loop to dump the contents to the console
    try {
        gzipReader = new BufferedReader(
               new InputStreamReader(
                new GZIPInputStream(
                 tmpIn)));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    if (gzipReader !=null){
        buffer.add(gzipReader);

    }

    }// end of while
  is.close();`

After I put the BUFFERreader into my linkedList and then retrieve it in the main and wants to print the content of the buffer, i have the exception:

java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)

Who can Help me???

Comment: Sorry mate, didn't get a word of what you're trying to say :(

Comment: When i open the stream of a file tar.gz, I can print the content of all single file, creating  BufferReader reader=  new BufferedReader(
               new InputStreamReader(
                new GZIPInputStream(
                 tmpIn))); 
 and then using read.reaLine()...so instead I wants  a puts the Buffeader into a LInkedLIst and then manage buffers into the main() of my program..it' clear now???

Answer (score 1):

From what I remember - in a tar.gz the compression is done last - I am not familiar with the class TarInputStream, but I imagine it would work something like

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream("myFile");
GZIPInputStream gzipIn = new GZIPInputStream(in);
TarInputStream tarIn=  new TarInputStream(gzipIn );
while((entryx = is.getNextEntry()) != null) {
    if (entryx.isDirectory()) continue;
    else {
          InputStream dataIn = new StreamingTarEntry(is,  entryx.getSize());
          //Process your data here - it is already uncompressed
    }
}
```

ie : A tar.gzip is a tar archive that has been gzipped

Comment: Yes is corrept. but If in your tar.gz you have gz files, so you have to keep dataIn and wrap into a BufferReader to keep the content of an single files, with bufferader.readLine(). But I don't want it!! I wouldLike keeps all bufferReader, puts them into linked list..and return them to the main(), and after play with the linked list. But if I try in the main() keep an buffer reader. with reader.ready() or reader.readLine() it throws ZLIb exception..it's clear??

Comment: Yeah - I think in order to do this you will need to copy the data to other OutputStreams as you read it (e.g.: ByteArrayOutputStream) - I very much doubt that TarInputStream supports reading multiple entries concurrantly.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that this is due to a *very* long-standing bug - see [here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4040920)

Comment: HUm....I really don't know if it is A bug. A think That when I iterate throug all files and then I have to create the buffer, and puts them to linked list, and then close the TarInpustream, is closure it's propagate to the buffers inside into the linkedLIst. So when I try in the main to puts their content, i THink that their EOF or a flag that represents the end of file is true. SO when i try to print the content a have the EXCEPTION.

IS POSIBLE?? How I can resolve the problem??

Answer (score 1):

I believe you've implemented `StreamingTarEntry` yourself, as there are no other references in Google and it is not part of the Ant API. From your other question, I think you followed [this blog post](http://hype-free.blogspot.com/2009/10/using-tarinputstream-from-java.html). Lacking the source to `StreamingTarEntry` this answer is partially a guess.

The `TarInputStream` in Ant only allows you to read data out of the current tar entry. You cannot save a reference to a position within the tar file and return to it, but must instead process each file as you reach it. Your `StreamingTarEntry` class must copy all the data from the current entry into a temporary location in memory or on disk before it calls `getNextEntry()` or `close()` on the `TarInputStream`.

Comment: Hum..it possible...so how I can copy all the data from the current entry??

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to implement a lot more code to do what you want. The tar format doesn't support random access. The `DeferredFileOutputStream` in Apache Commons-IO may help, but you'll still have to keep track of all the temporary files.

Comment: Oh my GOd !! I'ts a tragedy. I don't undestand why the developer didn't thought to follow the same strategy implement with ZIP file. With zip file i have a method getINputstream...DAMNSSS!!

Comment: It's not the developer. The zip file has a directory allowing random access, and the tar file does not: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)#Structure] vs [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(file_format)#Format_details]

Comment: :( . So I have a big PRoblem . SOB!!